# ng test don't find relative path

Tags: angular, testing, angular-cli, tsconfig, angular-devkit

I am trying to perform my first tests in Angular and I want to test a service, but when I run `ng test` it gives me an error in all the relative imports that I have defined in the tsconfi.json, such as for example

```
"@interceptors/*": [
        "./src/app/interceptors/*"
      ],
```

give me this error

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:17:44 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@interceptors/allhttprequests.interceptor' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an Angular application, there are typically multiple `tsconfig` files:

- `tsconfig.json`
- `tsconfig.app.json`
- `tsconfig.spec.json`

Typically, the `tsconfig.app.json` and `tsconfig.spec.json` files extend `tsconfig.json`.

`tsconfig.app.json` is used for the normal build. `tsconfig.spec.json` is used for the test build. ([More information.](https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration))

If the normal `ng build` doesn't give any errors about your [paths](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#paths), I would guess you have only added the `@interceptors/*` path to the `tsconfig.app.json`, but not the `tsconfig.spec.json`.

**I'm not 100% sure about the following:**

If you specified the `paths` in the `tsconfig.json`, but also have `paths` in `tsconfig.spec.json`, it could be that the `paths` in the latter one overwrites the `paths` in the `tsconfig.json`.